# How does this ruby function return anything?

Tags: ruby

I am working with legacy ruby code and I don't understand how this works.  The fnction is:

```
    def determine_caller(host)
      if host["name"] =~ /special/
        method(:call_special)
      else
        method(:call_normal)
      end
    end
```

later on the method is called:

```
caller = determine_caller(host_name)
```

The program eventually then uses caller as a variable as it runs a method in another class.  `call_special` and `call_normal` are methods later on in the program.

I believe this is defining a method to send to another method so it can later call the method as needed (either `call_special` or `call_normal`), but I don't understand how `determin_caller` returns anything.  I thought the `method` keyword invoked the method itself, but that can't be right, at least how I understand the program I am looking at.

Comment: Notice that if we have `def a(msg) puts "#{msg}, Bob" end`, `def say() method(:a) end` and `m = say #=> #<Method: Object#a>`, then `m.call("Hi") #=> Hi, Bob`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer, without going into ruby object model or anything, is that the last statement in a method is always returned. So if the callers name is special than return what ever value is returned when the method 'method' is called with those parameters

Comment: The last *value* seen is returned.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Object#method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-trunk/Object.html#method-i-method) method returns a [`Method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-trunk/Method.html). It doesn't call anything. (If it did, `method` would be an incredibly awful name for what it did.)

BTW: `method` is not a keyword and `determine_caller` is not a function. They are both methods.